# Simulating correlated binary outcome in R

Tags: r, binary, classification, simulation, correlation

I want to derive the dependent variable Y as highly correlated with the first 5 variables of the X independent variable matrix. Also, I want to edit 1 class to be 60% and 0 class to be 40%. How do I provide this? (Correlation status is more important to me than 60%-40%)

```
install.packages("MASS")

library(MASS)

# Data gen
p=30
n=50
pr <- seq(0.7, 0.4, length.out = p)
pr[1] <- 1
covmat <- toeplitz(pr)
mu= rep(0,p)
X_ <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n, mu = mu, Sigma = covmat))
X <- unname(as.matrix(X_))
vCoef = rnorm(ncol(X))
vProb =exp(X%*%vCoef)/(1+exp(X%*%vCoef))
Y <- rbinom(nrow(X), 1, vProb)
mydata= data.frame(cbind(X,Y))
```

Comment: Spearman or pearson correlation? How strong is 'highly'? Correlation is sth you do in regression analysis of continuously scaled variables and not on binary classification tasks.

Comment: I want it to be around 80%. correlation is not just for numerical variables. It can also be interpreted for categorical and binary variables.

Comment: Correlation data needs to be at least ordinal scaled. Since you have not specified the type of correlation needed, one is only safe in answering this question with numerical data.

Comment: The topic is unnecessarily dispersed. I have the necessary knowledge about correlation. For pearson and spearman, what you said about the least ordered structure is correct, but there are other correlation coefficients. I asked the question assuming that it was known which correlation was used in which situation. For me, numerically deriving the data according to the spearman and pearson correlation coefficient and then categorizing it is the solution; Deriving binary data according to the direct biserial correlation coefficient is also the solution.

Comment: The important thing for me is to provide the relevant ratio. It doesn't matter to me which way this is done. Please only reply about the proposed solution. Thank you.